# My append only work for 1 set of element jquery

Tags: jquery, input, append

My post's comments append only work for 1 post but i want this to be work on every post
[image]

```
  <body>
    <input type="text" id="postInt" /><button id="postBut">Post</button>
    <div id="postAppend"></div>
  </body>


 $("#postBut").click(function () {
        var postIntVal = $("#postInt").val();
        $("#postAppend").append(
          "<div id='postContainer'><p>" +
            postIntVal +
            "</p><input class='postCmntInt' /><button class='cmntBtn'>Comment</button><div class='postCmnts'></div>"
        );
        $(document).on("click", ".cmntBtn", function () {
          var postCmntInVal = $(".postCmntInt").val();
          $(".postCmntInt").after("<p>" + postCmntInVal + "</p>");
          $(".postCmntInt").val("");
        });
    
        $("#postInt").val("");
      });
```

Comment: Please include the relevant html, else it will be hard for us to reproduce the problem

Comment: Also I would not advice you to bind a click event inside another click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your html it's a bit hard to see. but I've changed to your jquery so it should work.

The below code is what i have changed.

```
$(document).on("click", ".cmntBtn", function() {
  var postCmntInVal = $(this).closest(".postContainer").find(".postCmntInt");
  postCmntInVal.after("<p>" + postCmntInVal.val() + "</p>");
  postCmntInVal.val("");
});
```

The problem is inside your `$(document).on("click", ".cmntBtn"` function. You don't specify the relate to the button that you click and the elements where it should do the work.

**Demo**

```js
$("#postBut").click(function() {
  var postIntVal = $("#postInt").val();
  $("#postAppend").append(
    "<div class='postContainer'><p>" +
    postIntVal +
    "</p><input class='postCmntInt' /><button class='cmntBtn'>Comment</button><div class='postCmnts'></div>"
  );
  $("#postInt").val("");
});
$(document).on("click", ".cmntBtn", function() {
  var postCmntInVal = $(this).closest(".postContainer").find(".postCmntInt");
  postCmntInVal.after("<p>" + postCmntInVal.val() + "</p>");
  postCmntInVal.val("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="postInt" /> <button id="postBut">post</button>
<div id="postAppend"></div>
```

Comment: could you please explain me what this code does   var postCmntInVal = $(this).closest(".postContainer").find(".postCmntInt");

Comment: @AfthalAd `.closest()` travels up the dom tree and search for the first element of that type. `.find()` does the oppesit of closest

Comment: why should i call my input element like this ? ( $(this).closest(".postContainer").find(".postCmntInt"); ) Can i call directly like this ($(".postCmntInt")  )

Comment: Problem is that if you use `$(".postCmntInt") ` then your click function does not know what .postcmnint you are "looking" for